# Mock a Class in a Class in a Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following code in a unit test

```
using Moq;
using OtherClass;
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        OtherClass.foo();
    }
}
```

Here is the other class

```
using ThirdClass;
public class OtherClass
{
    public void foo()
    {
        ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();
        third.bar();
    }
}
```

ThirdClass is still under development, but I want to be able to run my unit tests using moq. Is there a way to tell moq to mock ThirdClass inside TestClass without having OtherClass use/depend on moq? Ideally something like:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
    Mock<ThirdClass> third =  new Mock<ThirdClass>();
    third.setup(o => o.bar()).Returns(/*mock implementation*/);
    /*use third in all instances of ThirdClass in OtherClass*/
    OtherClass.foo();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `OtherClass` should be *provided* an instance of `ThirdClass` instead of *creating* one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `foo()` in class `OtherClass` is not unit testable because you creating new instance of real service and you cannot mock it.

If you want to mock it then you have to inject `ThirdClass` with dependency injection.

Example of `OtherClass` will be:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    private readonly ThirdClass _thirdClass;
    public OtherClass(ThirdClass thirdClass) 
    {
         _thirdClass = thirdClass;
    }
    public void foo()
    {
        _thirdClass.bar();
    }
}
```

Your test method with example of testing other class can be:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<ThirdClass> third =  new Mock<ThirdClass>();
    third.setup(o => o.bar()).Returns(/*mock implementation*/);

    OtherClass testObject= new OtherClass(third);

    // Action
    testObject.foo();

    // Assert
    ///TODO: Add some assertion.
}
```

You can use example try with [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx) DI container.

Comment: Should do `Mock<InterfaceName> third = new Mock<InterfaceName>();` when implementing an interface.

Comment: @DevendraLattu According to `Moq` mocked type can be "an interface, a class, or a delegate". Anyway in his example there are no interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas, guys. I ended up making another version of OtherClass.foo() that takes in an instance of ThirdClass, and in the version without it creates an instance. When testing I can call foo(mockThird), but users can just use foo().

```
using ThirdClass;
public class OtherClass
{
    public void foo(ThirdClass third)
    {
        third.bar();
    }
    public void foo()
    {
        foo(new ThirdClass());
    }
}
```

In the test class

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    Mock<ThirdClass> third =  new Mock<ThirdClass>();
    third.setup(o => o.bar()).Returns(/*mock implementation*/);
    OtherClass testObject= new OtherClass();

    testObject.foo(third);
}
```

Comment: I just want to let you know that according to regulations of this portal you cannot posting additional questions as answers. You have to edit your original question if is necessary or add as comments. If you editing question please make ensure to leave consistency with answer. Thanks