# C# unit testing with mstest and mockink unexpected error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

My testing code threw following error for unknow reason. Probably setting up mocking incorrectly but I have no idea how to do it right please help.

Message:
Test method GUI_VIS.MsTests.LoginTest.TestEmptyIsAdminWindow threw exception:
System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x => x.GetAllEmailAsync("Pepa", "Heslo", new Worker() {  })
Non-overridable members (here: GenericController.GetAllEmailAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Stack Trace:
Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) line 109
MethodExpectation.ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable) line 87 ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, MethodExpectation& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 219 ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 150 Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Func`4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) line 643
Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) line 498
Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression) line 452
LoginTest.TestEmptyIsAdminWindow() line 48
ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestEmptyIsAdminWindow()
    {
        Login login = new Login();

        Mock<GenericController> gcMock = new Mock<GenericController>();
        GenericController gc = new GenericController();

        login.IdBoxGet().Text = "John";
        login.PasswordBoxGet().Text = "Password";
        

        ObservableCollection<Worker> workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>() {
            new Worker
            {
                Name = "John",
                My_password = "Password",
                Role = "Boss"
            }
        };

        gcMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllEmailAsync("John", "Heslo", new Worker() { }))
            .ReturnsAsync(workers);
        
        var workersFromMocking = await gc.GetAllEmailAsync("John", "Password", new Worker() { });


        Assert.IsTrue(workersFromMocking[0].Name == "John");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are not using the  `gcMock` and `login` objects anywhere. In your case the SUT (system under test) is `gc`. A mock should be something that `gc` uses while calling the method that you want to test, not the GenericController itself.

Secondly, your error states that the `GetAllEmailAsync` method is not overridable. Moq can only work with abstract, virtual or interface methods. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905578/moq-non-overridable-members-may-not-be-used-in-setup-verification-expression) for clarification.